# Json.parse is null even when inside an if statement that say only run when it's not null?

Tags: javascript, json, object

In my script I put my script inside an if statement, but for some reason it's executing anyways, even when it's null. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("test") != null) {
window.localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("test"))));
} //end of if (window.localStorage.getItem("test") != null)
```

InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

ERROR: Execution of script 'test' failed! JSON.parse(...) is null

Comment: I would suggest you to check if the window.localStorage.getItem("test") !== null && window.localStorage.getItem("test") != undefined

Comment: @NickAth using `!=` to compare to `null` will also implicitly compare to `undefined`

Comment: What does console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("test")) output?

Comment: @CharlieWallace null, lol.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but you seem to be missing a `)` at the end of your second line. How are you running this code? In the browser? That error seems abnormal. Are you using any libraries?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain typo. I'm using tampermonkey.

Comment: I would just keep breaking down the code. As @NickAth commented the string "null" is not null. So what does this output? console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("test")))

Comment: @CharlieWallace null

Comment: @CharlieWallace The first null is black and the second null is gray

Comment: @CharlieWallace I just need a way for the if statement to not execute if it's null. Is that possible?

Comment: You can test against both null and the string "null" I think that will "fix" your specific issue.. I would be curious what is setting the test item to null in local storage. Notice that after a call to localStorage.removeItem("test") the item will be null (not the string "null"). Do you have code that is calling setItem("test", null) when it really should be calling removeItem?

Comment: Your code itself [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/txrj8anb/1/). I don't know anything about tampermonkey, but it's possible the problem comes something not directly related to your if statement. Those error messages are certainly suspicious because they're not the normal ones you'd get from incorrectly using `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @CharlieWallace No, but I have a script that refreshes the page exactly once: window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}